# check if a certain URL is opened in another tab

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I've already found that Question which is related to my one:
[check if a browser tab is already open so I don't make extra tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425440/check-if-a-browser-tab-is-already-open-so-i-dont-make-extra-tabs)

Is it as well possible to check if an URL you opened in a new tab has changed? 
Even if you don't own the URL you want to observe.
For example:

On my website, i would open a new tab like so:

```
var tabA = window.open('http://google.com','newTab');
```

and now the user changes to http://google.com/mail on that tab. Is there any chance to observe such an action?

edit: After giving it a second thought, this is probably not possible because of obvious security issues. Still wonder if there is anything you can find out, that is happening on a tab you have opened.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's feasible to see if a URL you entered in a new tab has changed for security reasons, especially if you don't control the URL you wish to see.