# persisting named window.open() tab

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, window.open

**Background.** I am working in Firefox. I am creating a documentation page with example queries (as hyperlinks) to my Apache Solr instance, running in the background.

**Issue.** I have found that when I send queries to Solr via hyperlinks (not an input element) I need to (1) let that search page load; (2) then execute the query.

Additionally, I have found that the named page (window / tab) that I reuse for the example queries needs to be focused to work correctly.

Hence, I (1) open the search page; (2) wait for that page to fully load, then open the query URL.

I have created a minimal example to show the issue, with a call to example.com in lieu of my search page (1., above); then after a time, the call to the the second URL (Google or Bing, in lieu of the search query in 2. above).

I believe the issue is related to the last sentence in the accepted answer here:

[check if a browser tab is already open so I don't make extra tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425440/check-if-a-browser-tab-is-already-open-so-i-dont-make-extra-tabs)

*... once the user refreshes the page, that reference is lost.*

In my code, if I use

```
my_window = window.open("", "my_tab");
```

then the `setTimeout()` executes, prints to console.

If I use

```js
my_window = window.open("", "my_tab").focus();
```

then (per the StackOver flow link above) I believe that the `my_window` object is lost, hence the `setTimeout()` never executes.

**Question:** how can I persist the named window / tab object (`my_window`)? `localStorage`? ...

---

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/vstuart/1yfeqkz9/8/

---

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script>
  function foo(obj) {
    globalThis.link = (obj.getAttribute("href"))
    console.log('[foo] link:', link);

    // ISSUE HERE:
    // my_window = window.open("", "my_tab").focus();
    // SOLUTION HERE, per accepted answer, below:
    my_window = window.open("", "my_tab");
    my_window.focus()
    
    my_window.location = "https://example.com/";

    setTimeout("bar(link)", 2000);
    return false;
    }

  function bar(link) {
    console.log('[bar] link:', globalThis.link);
    my_window.location=globalThis.link;
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
  <li><p><a target="my_tab" onclick="foo(this); return false;" href="https://dogpile.com/">Dogpile.com</a></p></li>

  <li><p><a target="my_tab" onclick="foo(this); return false;" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">DuckDuckGo.com</a></p></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant - I tried that suggestion in my real code and seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.focus()` on the line following the assignment.

```
my_window = window.open("", "my_tab")
my_window.focus()
```

When you use

```
my_window = window.open("", "my_tab").focus();
```

the problem is that my_window gets assigned the return value of [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus#return_value), not the return value of [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#return_value).

Comment: Sidebar comment re: `let my_window = ...` (answer above): vs. `my_window = ` (my code): the former throws a `Uncaught ReferenceError: my_window is not defined` in the console (in reference to `my_window` in `function bar()`, and the script fails. The latter declaration (without `let`) works fine.

Comment: Yes you're right.  I didn't notice that my_window was a global variable and used in other functions.